# Pre-processing within a Rails Controller create method does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial, and trying to implement the reply twitter-like functionality, ie. "**@122-john-smith**: hello there" should be a reply to user **122**.

I first tried filtering the *"@XXX-AAA-AAA"* part using a `before_filter`, but I decided to try it first in the very same `Micropost#create` action. So far I've got this `MicropostController`:

```rb
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
    before_filter :correct_user, only: [:destroy]
    #before_filter :reply_to_user, only: [:create]

    def index
    end

    def create
        @micropost=current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
        #Rails.logger.info "hoooola"
        regex=/\A@(\d)+(\w|\-|\.)+/i
        message=@micropost.content.dup
        isResponse=message.match(regex)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]
        @micropost.response=isResponse
        if @micropost.save
            flash[:success]="Micropost created!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            @feed_items=[]
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @micropost.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def correct_user
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
        redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
    end

    def reply_to_user
        regex=/\A@(\d)+(\w|\-|\.)+/i
        #I use [0] cause the output of match is a MatchData class with lots of bs
        mtch=params[:micropost][:content].match(regex)[0]
        #puts mtch
        #@micropost=current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
        if mtch != nil
            user_id=mtch.match(/\d+/)[0]
            @replied_user=User.find(user_id)
            @micropost.response=user_id unless @replied_user.nil?
        end
    end
end
```

And this is the snippet test I'm trying to pass:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "MicropostPages" do
    subject { page }
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { valid_signin user }
    describe "micropost creation" do
        before { visit root_path }
        describe "with invalid information" do
            it "should not create a micropost" do
                expect { click_button "Post" }.should_not change(Micropost,
                                                                                        :count)
            end
            describe "error messages" do
                before { click_button "Post" }
                it { should have_content('error') }
            end
        end
        describe "with valid information" do
            before { fill_in 'micropost_content', with: "Lorem ipsum" }
            it "should create a micropost" do
                expect { click_button "Post" }.should change(Micropost,
                                         :count).by(1)
            end
        end
    end
    ...

end
```

If I run these tests I get the follwing error:

```rb
Failures:

  1) MicropostPages micropost creation with invalid information should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button "Post" }.should_not change(Micropost, :count)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:14:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) MicropostPages micropost creation with invalid information error messages 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Post" }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:14:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:14:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**However** if I modify the tests and comment out all the *@XXX* filtering in the `Micropost#create` action:

```rb
    def create
        @micropost=current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
        #Rails.logger.info "hoooola"
        #regex=/\A@(\d)+(\w|\-|\.)+/i
        #message=@micropost.content.dup
        #isResponse=message.match(regex)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]
        #@micropost.response=isResponse
        if @micropost.save
            flash[:success]="Micropost created!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            @feed_items=[]
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end
```

The tests pass just fine and the new `Micropost` is not a `Nil` object.

It can't seem to find an explanation here.

Comment: Maybe its the regular expression `match(regex)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]` that causes the issue...

Comment: I tried it using `irb` and It returned the desired ID. Besides, shouldn't it in the worst case just write `Nil` in the `@micropost.response` field?

Comment: no, because you are accessing it with `[0]` this will throw the exact same error if the regex doesn't match.

Comment: oh, you are so righ! It indeed throws the same error when the regex doesn't match. Thank you. If you post an answer I can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
isResponse=message.match(regex)[0].match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Check if your two match calls actually match correctly. If the pattern is not found in your string, `nil` is returned and the `[0]` call is made on `nil`. There's two instances in this line alone where this could happen.

Try to spread it out over several lines and check the return values of your matches or extend your Regex to properly check the pattern in one go.

Comment: It seems this is exactly the issue, as also pointed out by @spas. I completely missed that. Also, I wonder what is the appropiate way to debug Controllers. I mean, how would you check the result of each `.match` if it's inside a controller? I mean I know how to do it in `irb`, but can't find an appropiate way via testing.

Comment: Well your tests are correctly performing the POST with all form params and your `create`-action gets executed. You should provide all sorts of input params as you need to expect the users to enter terribly wrong data by accident or sometimes on purpose. Check the results of your tests accordingly. The `create` call mustn't throw errors for any input. If it does, your validation checks for the correctness of input is not robust enough and you need to add additional conditions. This is not any different from calling your regex match on random values in `irb`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Although I was referring to a more explicit debugging *à la* `puts variablename`. So I can see actual contents of variables in the terminal.

Comment: Ah sorry. Just printing stuff to the console is very crude by todays standards. You can use the debug logs to print some values. You will need to look up how to use the Ruby Logger (or similar frameworks) yourself though as a simple comment wouldn't be enough to explain. If you have advanced IDEs like RubyMine, you can simply set a breakpoint in your method and then execute arbitrary code when execution stops there when in debug mode.

Comment: Oh, that's what I thought, only Ruby Logger. I will have to stick to that and keep `grep`*-ing* the tail of the `log/test.log` with some keywords. thanks!